# More efficient UI Overlay in 2D Unity game

Tags: c#, render, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D game with Unity that requires a UI canvas with only a simple text field that updates throughout the game. The UI canvas overlays the gameplay and just sits in the top left corner. I noticed, when looking at the performance of the game, there tends to be render spikes due to this UI element. This was communicated to me through elementCanvas.SendWillRenderCanvases(). Is there a way I could increase the efficiency of the text rendering, I feel this should not be a very demanding task for the CPU.

Comment: Maybe you update it too often? Maybe limit updating to e.g. once a second.

Comment: @FCin how would I go about doing that?

Comment: if you update it in an `Update()` method then maybe check if a second passed using `Time.time - lastTime > 1.0` and then update or start a coroutine with `StartCoroutine` that does `yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);`